# In java threa, how to call notify for a specificdoes notify work?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am following a book, where i got the wait() and notify() methods for thread. But slightly confused with the notify() method. Below is the code:

`class Q`

```
class Q {
    int n;
    boolean valueSet = false;

    synchronized int get() {
        while (!valueSet)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        System.out.println("Got: " + n);
        valueSet = false;
        notify();
        return n;
    }

    synchronized void put(int n) {
        while (valueSet)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        this.n = n;
        valueSet = true;
        System.out.println("Put: " + n);
        notify();
```

class `Producer`

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
    Q q;

    Producer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            q.put(i++);
        }
    }
```

class `Consumer`

```
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Q q;

    Consumer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            q.get();
        }
```

class `PCFixed`

```
class PCFixed {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Q q = new Q();
        new Producer(q);
        new Consumer(q);
        System.out.println("Press Control-C to stop.");
    }
}
```

Now my confusion is that- inside get() method of class Q, is the wait() method is making the current thread wait until put() method's notify() method is called? right?

So, here comes my 2 questions:

1. If put() method's notify()- notifies the thread which was kept waiting for get methods wait() and vise versa.
   Here its only two thread, so one can notify each other. What would have happened if there was another method(Lets say get2()) & had a wait() inside it too. How would have put notifies one specific threads method-which is in waiting() state(without notifying the other one, which might also be in waiting state )?
2. If i am worng in my previous concept, which is notifying each others. Than what is the real case & how does it work?

Comment: [Java tutorials on `wait` and `notify`/`notifyAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Comment: valueSet needs to be volatile.

Comment: What is a 'threa', and what's a 'specificdoes'?

Comment: @Nathan Hughes: Since `valueSet` is accessed from within `synchronized` blocks only there is no need to make it `volatile`.

Comment: @Holger: that is true. i was being too hasty here, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`notify()` will wake up *one* thread that has been waiting on an object.  If you want to wake up all of them, you'd need to use `notifyAll()`.  `notify()` by itself doesn't allow you to specify which object wakes up (I believe it's implemented with a FIFO queue, but I'm not positive on that).  If you need to control specifically which thread wakes up, you would need to either use multiple lock objects or use a more complex data structure that would allow you to specify which thread to wake up.

Answer (score 0):

When the JVM runs your `while(!valueSet)`, it says to itself, "I can see from the code that `valueSet` is not changed in the loop, so I'm going to be clever and save time by not rechecking it each time through the loop."

In order to tell the JVM that a field might be changed by another thread while a method is running, you can declare that field to be `volatile`. So, just changing `boolean valueSet` to `volatile boolean valueSet` should fix the problem.

Also, as noted by Chris, you probably want to use `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()`. If you have multiple consumers or producers, you might get a situation like this:

```
Value not set, C1 and C2 waiting.
P1 produces, notifying C1 to run.
P2 produces and blocks waiting for the value to be not set.
C1 completes, notifying C2 to run. (Oops -- should have run P2)
C2 is still blocked and goes back to waiting.
```

You could also avoid this by having separate monitors for read and write, so that `get()` would wait on one monitor and then notify the other. But `notifyAll()` is simpler.

Comment: Since there’s a `wait()` call inside the loop the JVM knows that upon return, the values of all variables might have been changed. That’s the intentional way of how `synchronized`, `wait`, and `notify` work. There’s no need for additional `volatile` modifiers. And, by the way, don’t try to fix a problem when the questioner never said to have a problem.